# Copied Selenium script on different local machine not running using testng.xml

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have selenium test script written on one of my local machine and it works fine on it using testng.xml

I have copied the same script to different local machine and am trying to execute it using testng.xml by right clicking on testng.xml and selecting run as testng suite but nothing happens.

No error is shown neither script is executed or browser is instantiated.

There is no error in the project. I have added all the requred jar files.

Can any one help me with any pointer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="XXXXX">    
    <test name="testScripts">
        <parameter name="superAdmin" value="superAdmin"/>   
        <parameter name="participant" value="participant"/> 
            <classes>
                <class name="testScripts.ParticipantSide" />
            </classes>
    </test>
```

Running testng.xml from run as > configuration and specifying the suite, runs the scripts

It is running by manually specifying the suite to execute. It is still not running directly via path right click on testng.xml > Run As > TestNg Suite

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have used?

Comment: Selenium code. Are you using java? Please post the test code.

Comment: I can copy the testng code. There is a lot of project code. Testng execution is not happening.

Comment: Please find testng code in questions

Comment: Try running that script directly in debug mode first, just to verify it is instantiating or not and observe console.
OR check execution path of testng.xml file on new local machine.

Comment: I have tried running code in debug mode. TestNG does not run in debug mode.

Comment: Can you post the testscript code?

Comment: I would not be able to do so. But it runs perfectly on my other local machine

Comment: Is your script have @parameters annotation ?

Comment: R u reading those parameter value in your script?

Comment: Yes script has @parameter annotation. Those paramater are read in script.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the full path of your class as local machine is different. Try to build and compile or clean the entire source code and try again. Because `testNG.xml` seems to be the correct one.

Comment: Running testng.xml from run as > configuration and specifying the suite, runs the scripts

Comment: Which path has to be modified. Can you please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Facing this very similar issue after I updated TestNG yesterday. In my case, I haven't copied Selenium Suite from anywhere, it was built from scratch on the very same machine that I am using at the moment.

But after I updated TestNG yesterday, I now have to go through Run > Run Configuration > path\to\testng.xml (in Suite field) and then Run it.

It doesn't work if I simply right click on testng.xml and do Run As > TestNG Suite